# regex to remove last four characters

Tags: shell-script, scripting, regular-expression, for

Is there a way I could eliminate the last four characters with regex in the below one line script as I convert .wav files into .mp3 files. As of right now my single line script produces files ending in `.wav.mp3`

```
for i in *.wav; do avconv -i "$i" "$i".mp3;done
```

Produces the below output

```
    Sanctify, Separate, & Success Success.wav.mp3
    There four types of love.wav.mp3
    Theres too much love to let you fail.wav.mp3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want a regex, you want to use Bash's [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to remove the file extension in transit:

```
for i in *.wav; do avconv -i "$i" "${i%.*}".mp3; done
```

Here, `"${i%.*}"` is expanded as the pattern at *the end of the parameter*, as defined by everything (`*`) after the `.` deleting the shortest match, ie., `.wav`.

You could also do a literal substitution with `"${i/.wav/.mp3}"`.